# Square roots in inequalities

Tags: inequality

If I have the inequality

$$x^2 > b^2,$$

is this always equal to $\;|x| > |b|\quad ?$

Answer (score 3):

Just a clarification here in what is happening, and your use of the term "equal":

$$x^2 \gt b^2\, \text{ if and only if } \,|x| > |b|.$$

That is *not* to say that the inequalities are *equal*, but *yes*, they are *equivalent* inequalities: they share the same solution set. What's true of one, is true of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes because both sides are positive and thus the square root can be taken and then you use the fact that $\sqrt {x^2}= |x|$

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not true if you are talking about complex numbers. For example, let $b$ be $i$ and let $x$ be $-1$. Then $(-1)^2=1 > i^2=-1$, but $\mathopen|-1\mathclose|=\mathopen|i\mathclose|=1$.

Comment: I'm sure that the OP is talking about $b,x\in\Bbb R$ only. In $\Bbb C$, then inequality $x^2>b^2$ usually does not make sense, as it is not possible to define a total order $>$ such that $\Bbb C$ is an ordered field.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for this.